# Stay in same page while opening a modal

Tags: angular, redirect, modal-dialog, mean-stack, ng-bootstrap

Well, i have this code in my navbar

**navbar.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
  ...
       <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" (click)="openLogin()">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/']">login</a>
      </li>
...
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" (click)="openRegister()">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/']">Register</a>
      </li>
...
</nav>
```

A modal is opened after I click either register or login, but the thing is that, when the modals are opened, the user is redirected to the homepage, but I want to stay in the same page where the user is, but i dont know how to do it. Any ideas? I'm working with angular2 and ng-bootstrap.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are probably telling the router to redirect the user to the root of your site `/`

It can work removing completely the `routerLink` attribute

```
<a class="nav-link">login</a>
```

Comment: Changing the '/' for '.' didnt work, but removing the  [routerLink]="['/']" did. The problem with this is that the effect of the mouse becoming a hand changes for the effect when the mouse hovers text.

Comment: Ok.. does it work if you put in `routerLink` the route of your current page? For example, if `navbar.html` template is associated with `/login` route, you can try `[routerLink]="['/login']"`. It shouldn't redirect you if the URL and the parameters are not changed..let me know ;)

Comment: No, it doesnt work neither! It opens a page as if the modal.html were the source code of it

Comment: Ok, I solved it! I create a css class named modal-hover, added my register and login links to it and did this

.modal-hover{cursor: pointer}

Also, i removed the routerLink attribute, and thats it! It works as i want, thanks for your help!

Comment: There's probably a way to do it using just angular's router, but that's nice ;) Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [feature](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23709) `role="button"` added in June 2020:

```
<a (click)="open(mymodal)" role="button" class="text-decoration-underline">{{ your-text-here }}</a>
```

[Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/reboot/#pointers-on-buttons)